# Empty XML Columns during SQL Server replication

Tags: sql, xml, replication

We have a merge replication setup on SQL Server that goes like this: 1 SQL server at the office, another SQL server traveling around the world. The publisher is the SQL server at the office.

**In about 1% of the cases, two of our tables with a column of XML Data type (not bound to a schema) are replicated with rows containing empty XML columns.** ( This only happened when data is sent from the "traveling server" back home, but then again, data seems to be changed more often there ). We only have this in prod. environment ( WAN replication ).

Things i have verified:

- The row is replicated, as the last modification date on the row is refreshed but the xml column is empty. Of course it is not empty on the other SQL Server.
- No conflicts are displayed in the replication conflicts UI.
- It is not caused by the size of the data inside the XML Column as some are very small.
- Usually, the problem occurs in batch. ( The xml column of 8-9 consecutive rows will be empty )
- The problem occurs if a row was inserted OR updated. No pattern there.
- The problem seems to occur, but this is pure speculation on my part when the connection is weaker. ( We've seen this problem happen more often when the server was far away as compared to when it was close by. )

Sorry if i have confused some things, I am not really a DBA, more of a DEV with knowledge of SQL but since the application using the database keeps getting blamed for the problems ( the XML column must not be empty!! ) I have taken it at heart to try and find the problem instead of just manually patching the data each time ( Whats the use of replication if you have to do that? )

If anyone could help out with this problem, or at least suggest some ways of being able to debug / investigate this it would be greatly appreciated. 
I did search alot on google and I did find this: [Hot Fix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/948628/) . But we do have the latest service pack and the problem seems a bit different.

fyi: We have a replication setup locally here but the problem never occurs. We will be trying a WAN simulator on it as well to see if that can help.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit: hot fix is now available for my issue: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2591902**

After logging this issue with Microsoft, we were able to reproduce the problem without a slow link ( Big thanks to the competent escalation engineer at Microsoft ). The repro is a bit different from our scenario, but highlights the timing issue we were getting perfectly.

Create 2 tables – One parent one child (have a PK-FK relationship)

Insert 2 rows in the parent table

Set up replication – configure merge agent to run ON DEMAND

Sync

Once all is replicated:

On the PUBLISHER: delete one row from the parent table

On the SUBSCRIBER: Insert 2 rows of data that references the parentid you deleted above

Insert 5 rows of data that references the parentid that will stay in the table

Sync, Merge agent will fail, Sync again, Merge agent will succeed

Missing XML data on the publisher on the 5 rows.

Seems it is a bug that is in SQL Server 2005/2008 and 2008R2.
It will be addressed in a hot fix in 2008 and up. ( As SQL Server 2005 is no longer being altered )

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to start out by slapping a bandaid on this perplexing situation to buy some time to fully investigate and fix (or more likely get MS to fix it). [SQL Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/) is an excellent tool that might help.

Comment: We have a bandaid scenario in place but they are very annoying as the server often travels in a plane and is unavailable for periods of time between cities. We only have support calls with Microsoft for non production servers so we need to reproduce this problem in test then I guess we will get them involved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Figured i'd put an update here as this issue got me a few gray hairs and I am somewhat closer to a solution now.

I finally had some time to work on this and managed to reproduce this issue in our test environment, using a WAN simulator and slowing down the link and injecting some random packet loss. ( to best simulate the production environment where the server is overseas on a really bad line ).

After doing some SQL tracing, and some verbose logging here are my conclusions: 
When replicating a row with an XML column, the process is done in 2 steps. First an insert is done of the full row but with an empty string for the XML column. Right after, an update is done this time with the XML column having data. Since the link is slow, in some situations a foreign key violation occured. 
In this scenario, Table2 depends on Table1. After finishing replicating table1, and starting to replicate table2 (Enumration of insert/updates which takes time on a slow link), some entries were added to table1 and table2. Therefore some inserts on Table2 failed because Table1 entries were not in the database and were only going to be replicated next batch. The next time the replication occured, no more foreign key violations occured, however when it tried to insert the row that had previously failed in Table2 ( XML column row ), the update part of it was missing ( I could see that in the SQL profiler ) and that is why the row ended up after all was done with an empty XML.

Setting "Enforce for replication" to false on the foreign keys seems to address the problem, however I do still think that this whole process should work with the option set to true.

I logged a support call with Microsoft for this. I have sent the traces and logs to Microsoft and will see what they have to say.

I've read this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152529(v=SQL.90).aspx. But for me, setting this option to false is kind of a work around, no?

What do you guys think?

ps: Hope this is clear, tried to explain it the best I could. English is not my first language.